# How to get class information in Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp

For example, I want to see a list of available accessors of a slot from the REPL instead of jumping to the source. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure there's a way to get a list of `accessor`s easily. The object inspection functions tend to be exported from implementation-specific packages. You can take a look at the [`package` file](https://github.com/Inaimathi/cl-mop/blob/master/package.lisp) of [`cl-mop`](https://github.com/Inaimathi/cl-mop) to see where they are. The relevant lines are

```
...
 (:shadowing-import-from
  #+openmcl-native-threads #:ccl
  #+cmu #:pcl
  #+sbcl #:sb-pcl
  #+lispworks #:hcl
  #+allegro #:mop
  #+clisp #:clos
  #:class-slots #:slot-definition-name)
...
```

The project also exports [`slot-names`](https://github.com/Inaimathi/cl-mop/blob/master/cl-mop.lisp#L9-L13) and [`to-alist`](https://github.com/Inaimathi/cl-mop/blob/master/cl-mop.lisp#L32-L33) methods that do exactly what they sound like.

If you're in [`slime`](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/), rather than a plain command-line REPL, you can use `slime-inspect`. If you use it to inspect a `class`, you'll see (among other things) a list of methods that specialize on it (you need to inspect a `class` this way, so if you have an instance, you need to call `class-of` on it first).

Comment: Great. `slime-inspect` solved this problem. I can inspect an object in greater details and look at its reader and writer.

Comment: Also note the slime inspect shortcut `ctrl-c shift-I` (that's a capital 'i') which is super handy. You can also use `*` in slime-inspect just like you can in the repl.